# Python3 UnicodeDecodeError, can't read file with cp1251 encoding

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, encoding

I've upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 (Python 3.4.3) to 16.04 (Python 3.5.2). Now my script can't read a file with the encoding cp1251:

```
with open(fs[0], encoding='cp1251') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
```

It gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/Rad/get_info.py", line 9, in <module>
    r.get_tests()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/Rad/rad.py", line 166, in get_tests
    s = f.readlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 13: character maps to <undefined>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Debugging leads to the this code in the file `/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/cp1251.py`:

```
class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
```

What was changed in this Python version and how to avoid this error?

Comment: are you sure that your file is cp1251 encoded ? what about using utf8 ?

Comment: I second @ChihebNexus, the codecs module actually says `'\ufffe'   #  0x98 -> UNDEFINED`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about encoding.

Comment: @MichaelO. well i think opening your file in `'rb'` will avoid this issue.

Comment: @ChihebNexus This gives an error `ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`

Comment: like the error says, `open(your_file, 'rb')` without and encoding argument. But notice that the readed data will be in binary mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found [a way](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-July/090599.html) to fix this error that works both in Python 2 and 3:

```
import codecs
...........
with codecs.open(fs[0], encoding='cp1251', errors='replace') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
```